# Convert an int to an ascii char c#

Tags: c#, ascii

I have an int and I want to display the associate letter. For example, if the int is "1", I want to display "a".

I have a variable "word" and I want to add this letter in it. This is my code :

```
word += (i+96).ToString();
Console.WriteLine(word);
```

But in the console, I have a list of number. I found `Encoding.ASCII.GetChars` but it wants a `byte` in parameter. How should I do please ?

Comment: Can't you just use Convert.ToChar() or cast it (char)i ?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use one of these methods to convert number to an **ASCII / Unicode / UTF-16**  character:

You can use these methods convert the value of the specified 32-bit signed integer to its Unicode character:

```
char c = (char)65;
char c = Convert.ToChar(65);
```

But, [`ASCII.GetString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/38b953c8(v=vs.110).aspx) decodes a range of bytes from a byte array into a string:

```
string s = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(new byte[]{ 65 });
```

Keep in mind that, `ASCIIEncoding` does not provide error detection. Any byte greater than hexadecimal 0x7F is decoded as the Unicode question mark ("?").

So, for your solving your problem you can use one of these methods, for example:

```
word += (char)(i + 96);
```

Comment: I've already tried with this method but I forgot the brackets and it didn't work. Now it's working perfectly ! Thanks ! :)

Comment: @Erlaunis Glad to help.

Comment: Good answer. Actually, the last one is the only one that involves ASCII. The first three all take Unicode/UTF-16 code units. And, of course, the results are all Unicode/UTF-16 code units (`char` is one code unit; `string` is a counted sequence of code units). It's important to know which character set and encoding your are using. ASCII is rare.

Comment: Perhaps for codes > 127, if codepage become important something similar to:
`int cp = 1252;
string s = Encoding.GetEncoding(cp).GetString(new byte[]{ 128 });`
may do the trick for ANSI codepage "Latin 1 Windows" in this case.